# Fast copy/rename database, not mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, copy

I would like to keep a "default" setup for a database on a testing server, which can be used to "restore" a "dirty" testing database back to the default state.

mysqldump is very fast, done in a few seconds. But restoring from the dump takes 5-10 minutes. If I could drop the test database, copy the "default" over to the test database *directly* somehow, perhaps by copying the database's system files, that would be awesome.

Comment: does this help? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25449/can-i-copy-a-mysql-database-by-copying-the-files-what-do-the-files-contain-exac

Comment: Or [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.3/index.html)

Comment: @Aleksandrus `mysqlhotcopy` is only for MyISAM, and I'm using nearly all InnoDb. The user's other suggestion seems like it has potential, although the tools he mentions are completely new to me.

Comment: @jkavalik they mention faster restore time, so that could be a possible solution for me as well. I didn't realize Percona had this free products.

Comment: @ButtleButkus use it in case you cannot stop the server. If you can then full binary files swapping might be faster (or some filesystem snapshots even).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a lot of indexes and/or you have not set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is too small on your testing server.  If you have "indexed every column", repent!

A way to get a full disk copy instantly, regardless of its size, is to use LVM.  You would have the database sitting there, then you would take a "snapshot" and use the snapshot.  Eventually would would toss the snapshot.